# Python pyodbc Driver for SQL Server (macOS M1 PRO)

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc

Now that Microsoft SQL Server 17.8 supports ARM64, I have been still getting the same issues as before where

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.8.1.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib}',
                       server='server',
                        database='DB',
                        uid='id',
                        pwd='password')
```

Still seems to have no luck opening the driver

> ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.8.1.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

When I run ODBC config in terminal it looks like this

```
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/yingzhouxia/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

But I have also I located the Microsoft odbcinst file here  `/opt/homebrew/opt/msodbcsql17@17.8`

and the Driver `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.8.1.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib`

The one under`/etc/odbcinst.ini` is empty the other file returns

```
(base) yingzhouxia@MAC msodbcsql17@17.8 % cat odbcinst.ini 
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/homebrew/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

I have been trying to fix this for a long time please could someone help me out thx!

Comment: Did you install `unixodbc` using Homebrew? I would expect to see paths `/opt/homebrew/etc/odbcinst.ini`, `/opt/homebrew/etc/odbc.ini` and `/opt/homebrew/etc/ODBCDataSources`. Have a read through [Issue 53](https://github.com/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/issues/53) for hints.

Comment: Yes `unixodbc` is installed using Homebrew

Comment: Did anyone found the solution for the same? If yes please share because I still cannot connect Python with SQL Server in M1